# Is it possible to gather or call all element that contains 'required' attribute to one event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit, required

I have `sumbit` button that triggers another function when clicked. It is not allowing the form to be submitted when the required fields were not filled but still triggers the other event because I put it like this.

```
$('#SubmitButton').click(function() {
        $('.bs-example-modal-sm').modal('show');
    });
```

The modal still shows even though I don't want it to happen when those required fields were not filled. Now, I want to call all element that contains `required` attribute to an event in `javascript` or `jquery` so that I can validate them together. Is it possible? Or do you have other suggestions to meet my desired output? Thank you.

Comment: if(true){//do something}

Comment: @C-linkNepal as if i don't know `if` statements?

Comment: I told you about true not if statement... if something is true then only call the method.....

Comment: You can use `$("input[required]")` to get all the input elements that contain a `required` attribute

Comment: I'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$("input[required]")` to get all the input elements that contain a `required` attribute.

Comment: Thank you, not only because it gives the solution but also from truly understanding the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use jquery for such a small thing when HTML5 can do it easily. Use the `required` attribute. For reference see:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: yes, I appreciate your comment. But please try to understand the question first before giving your suggested answer. Or state if you want more clarification from the question.

Comment: Yes I understand your question. You want to somehow validate you form and as I said above `required` and `pattern` attributes will do just that(without javascript or jquery) in a much easier way, just check out the links. And I have answered your question according to your this line "Or do you have other suggestions to meet my desired output?"

Comment: `Is it possible to gather or call all element that contains 'required' attribute to one event in Javascript?` - my `textfields` has `required` attribute already, what am I trying to say if is it possible to just call them all together in one event. Events are on `javascript` and not on markups.

Comment: And thats because you want to validate them, Right! For that use `pattern`. Pattern ensures that the content entered in the textboxes is of the correct type. But still if you want then yes it can be called like this:First assign a unique id to each of your form elements and then call them all like this `document.getElementById("id of your element").value`. Assign these values to seperate variables and then do whatever you wish to.